I think my cat stepped on my keyboard and activated modes in iTerm that I do not want
Suddenly, when I execute a command that fills the buffer with content greater than the height of the screen, I am seeing a bar at the top of the screen showing the command that was run.  How do I turn this off?

Also, now when clicking on the iterm window, a blue border appears with short cut icons on the top right corner...

I have gone through all the preferences and can't find what these two modes are and how I can turn them off because they are both driving me crazy!

Have you ruled out that this is not a side-effect of using OMZ? You can try a shell in standard macOS Terminal (to see if the problem travels), or temporarily disabling OMZ (to see if it goes away). Also, could you update the question with your iTerm2 version & macOS version please?

It’s a feature of the terminal app you have installed. The cat is exonerated even if they upgraded iterm on you without preapproval…
